# Is "right hand of" means right hand of anybody else?

Tags: meaning, idioms, terminology, vocabulary

Idiom meaning of **"right hand of"**

Example.

Right hand of GOD.

Comment: What research have you done to find an answer? I'm quite sure there are a lot of sources out there, considering that your example is on wikipedia with exact wording.

Comment: Have you any specific doubt about its meaning?

Comment: Vince, please please [edit your question](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/186987/edit) and let us know where you've looked for an answer, and what you've found.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an English idiom, but a literal translation of a Biblical Hebrew expression.

*Yamin* means, primarily, the right hand in its aspect as the instrument of power and dexterity; the "right hand of God" might be better translated as the "strong arm of God". Attributive use of the word in construct case (= 'of the right hand') to designate direction is secondary: it signifies both *right-hand* and *South*—apparently the Hebrews oriented themselves literally, toward the rising sun in the East.

The Biblical use has led to an independent English idiom: "right hand" or "right-hand man" designates an assistant whom a leader particularly relies on to effect his policies.

Answer (score 0):

[The right hand of God](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_hand_of_God),  has symbolic meanings of omnipotence and justice:

> - (dextera Domini "right hand of the Lord" in Latin) or God's right hand may refer to the hand of God often referred to in the Bible and common speech as a metaphor for the omnipotence of God and as a motif in art. The Archangel Michael is also often referred to as "the Right Hand of God".
> - It is also a placement next to God in Heaven, in the traditional place of honour, mentioned in the New Testament as the place of Christ at Mark 16:19, Luke 22:69, Matthew 22:44 and 26:64, Acts 2:34 and 7:5 1 Peter 3:22 and elsewhere.

Source:http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_hand_of_God

Comment: In the case of Diego Maradona, it is his [left hand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand_of_God_goal#.22Hand_of_God.22_goal).